# Connecting a Pseudo-Neutral to Pig Tail of GFCI

Tags: protection

In my country. Our homes mostly don't have third ground wires connecting to the neutral wires of the utility pole because contractors are all into cost cutting. Although some important facilities have them. My old house didn't have neutral/ground lines and it's so far to the utility pole. Someone suggested at the home improvement forum how to provide neutral to the GFCI breaker input I bought for a project so as to power its circuit which needs 120V, but he fell short of providing any more details. He said: "on the need for 120V to power the GFCI's guts, here's an idea: a North American panel in the Phillippines has a neutral bus that is completely unused. Use it. Install a 5 VA (that should be enough) 240V center-tap autotransformer in there, tie the center tap to the neutral bar. Then land all the GFCI pig's tails on the neutral bar".

I have a Siemens QF260A GFCI Breaker:

[image: 3]

The poster instructs me to connect the GFCI Pigtail to the 240v autotransformer center-tap. Can it really work? Any possible problem that can occur?

Comment: I leave this in a comment because while technically correct, actually implementing this answer is, at the very best, highly questionable.  I'd be looking into installing grounding wires on the critical circuits if I could.  The red leads look like secondary leads.  What you're proposing would "work" to the extent that the GFCI circuits wouldn't trigger when you don't want them to -- but it's because you're fooling the thing into not triggering ever.  There could be flashes of blue light and smoke and screaming in the bathroom, and the GFCI wouldn't trigger.

Comment: I just got the autotransformer picture from google. I couldn't find a 240V center-tap autotransformer picture.. just assume there are 3 primary input with centertap at middle. So just imagine the red lines above are the primary hot lines and the black wire the primary neutral.. and the brown one the secondary wires.

Comment: What kind of service do you have - two wire 230V grounded?  If so, you have to be very careful with the grounding when using a transformer.  An isolation transformer that creates a "separately derived system" might be the best / simplest / safest.

Comment: Just 2 hot wire 240V and usually not grounded (but can be grounded by simply adding a third wire). An electrical engineer was advising me to ground the secondary of the isolation transformer.. this is to shunt common mode surges. Common mode means hot to ground or neutral to ground.. but if my equipment connected to that transformer doesn't have any ground..then should I really ground the secondary? The GFCI would be connected to 240v-120v step down isolation transformer to power a 120v Surge Protector Device to get lower clamping voltage.240V surge protectors have over 1000v clamping voltage.

Comment: Are you sure your two wire service is ungrounded?  I am betting one of your service wires is 0v to ground.  This is important.

Comment: No. Because if I measure either of the hot lines by connecting one voltmeter lead to one hot line and one lead to soil. I measure 120V. When I measure both, it's 240V which is what we used... because we never used 120V in our country. For panel bus with neutral connected to utility pole.. it's 120V line to neutral. It's same as the USA ac power. Why what is the consequence of this in grounding the secondary of the isolation transformer?

Comment: OK that is helpful.  (Are you in the Phillipines?)

Comment: Yup. So must I ground the secondary of the isolation transformer to shunt common mode surges even though I have no equipments with metal case connected to the transformer?

Comment: Grounding the secondary of the transformer will help with surge protection as mentioned in your other comment and makes it possible for an equipment ground conductor to clear ground faults.  (No idea what your code says about EGC.)

Comment: But the transformer is connected only to cctv cameras and fire detectors which dont have any ground conductor. What good would grounding the secondary do? It suppresses only common mode surges which is hot/neutral to ground which those cameras/detectors dont have. Remember grounding the secondary wont help in normal mode surges which are line to line or line to neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you would hook the red "outside" wires to a 240V supply, i.e. A different 240V breaker.  That would cause the center black wire to synthesize a midpoint at ~120V.

Since the GFCI breaker is getting its outside wires from the exact same bus bars, the center black would appear as a neutral to it, and should suffice to power it.

GFCI devices don't care about safety earthing, so you're all set.

It wouldn't work to attach the two red wires to the outputs of the GFCI breaker; those are inside the GFCI protected zone, and you intend to use the black (pseudo neutral) wire outside that zone, so it would be a fault, exactly what the GFCI is designed to detect and trip on!

There is one problem, though.  There is no listed method for attaching supply power to that breaker; it's designed to snap into a Siemens service panel and engage its bus bars.  Therefore your best bet is to get a small Siemens panel that is  compatible.   That panel could support several such breakers: you could set it up as a subpanel.

Comment: I kept visualizing your setup. But could it form a complete circuit.. I mean between the GFCI breaker neutral input and one of the the external autotransformer hot line? If you or someone has illustration.. please show it because I can't imagine how they can form a complete circuit.

Comment: @Samzun you can't have a device partially hooked up inside the GFCI protected zone, and partially outside it.  That violates a basic rule of GFCI. Also, how is the GFCI breaker going to power up if it doesn't have a neutral supply?  If it doesn't power up, how will it supply power to the red wires to synthesize a neutral?

Comment: It's getting confusing. I'll recap so you can see where I might get some idea wrong. First what kind of autotransformer were you referring. Is it the one with 2 hot input and 2 outputs (with one of these the neutral)?  Or did you mean the neutral must be one of the leads of the primary? Are there autotransformer like this? Pls describe the autotransformer you meant or show a picture of some kind. My picture above is wrong so it even confuse me more if your reply pertains to it or other autotransformer I can't imagine.

Comment: If you ignore the brown wires and leave them disconnected, the one in your pic is fine.  That's what I figured you planned to do.   The point is the neutral is on the same primary as the endpoint wires.  That's an autotransformer, which is what you have been talking about.  General observation, the stuff you're trying to do here is way too complex to walk you through by rote as a step by step -- you need to understand the underlying concepts.  Keep at it. Aim to learn broadly for life, rather than learn barely enough to rush this project done.

Comment: I think I got your idea. But in the autotransformer in my country, all they have are 2 input of 240v and 2 output of 120v version. There is no neutral (or 3 line input) simply because we don't have any neutral. So I need to order your suggested autotransfomer abroad too. Must I google for "3 wire input autotransformer" (do you have specific text to search so I can find the spec directly?)

Comment: Those aren't autotransformers.  Didn't we discuss this at length over on DIY?  The defining characteristic of an autotransformer is it doesn't have a secondary, but does have more than 2 taps on the primary.   (Well it can have a secondary, but all the autotransforming is done on the primary. For instance if the above transformer had a 24V secondary, you could use that for thermostat  and doorbell. )

Comment: Please see the wiring illustration in the updated original post above. Is the wiring connection what you have in mind?

Comment: The diagram is correct. I do not agree with the use of the word "secondary" to describe the middle taps on what I call the "primary" though.

Comment: I finally got your idea. My 2 pcs of Siemens would arrive on Saturday. I'd try them and hopefully no smoke, lol. About how to connect the breakers to a panel. I'll bring the breaker to a local panel maker and see if it can fit their bus or let them make a tiny bus enough to connect it to the breaker separately (without the whole panel) and just tape the exposed parts. This would work too. Won't it.

Comment: Harper, my 2 Siemens have arrived.. they are wider than ordinary breaker and the fit is tight for ready made panel.. see:   https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/923/QzJor3.jpg  so I let them make a special one that is 1 inch wider each side and getting it in 5 days. Say. I couldn't find 5va autotransformer.. minimum is 50 watts.. can I use it to power 2 or more Siemens breaker neutral?  Or should it be only one autotransformer per breaker? Thanks.

Comment: With North American style panels, you can't mix and match breakers.  The shape of the busbars is too different,  Siemens breakers go only in Siemens panels.  Get one of those, easy peasy.  North American panels tend to be 14.5" wide which fits in standard wall cavities, this leaves plenty of room for the long breakers.   One transformer can power any number of breakers, >5VA is fine.

Comment: But as you can see in the picture. The bus fits the Siemens perfectly.. only the panel is short horizontal.. so I let them add 1 inch per side. Why can't you mix and match breakers when the panel is rated for 100 Ampere.. and my load only less than 10 Ampere. I just need the GFCI function.. where if it detects 5mA leakage.. then it trips.. any reference of other reasons why you can't mix and match? Ordering from amazon would have shipping cost more expensive than the panel, and I can't see the logic of not mixing and matching breakers.

Comment: I installed the 2 pcs GFCI 2-pole breakers with the neutral connected to the centertap of the autotransformer, it's working perfectly. Thanks. But autotransformer doesn't last 40 years. When the primary shorts or secondary opens, the 240v voltage can transfer to the secondary. I plan to install 7 gfci breakers powered by same 50va transformer. So is there any way I can use isolation transformer to power up the neutral of the siemens gfci breakers so in the event of fault, the primary voltage won't get to the secondary frying up all 7 gfci breaker circuits simultaneously?

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that transformers fail, and do so with that particular kind of short. (Wasn't your entrée into this community asking us about that very thing?)   It wouldn't surprise me if there were consumer travel adapter products of Chinese provenance that failed just that way, but that experience would not apply to a wound transformer as a component.  I would expect a transformer to fail open, but really I would expect a transformer to fail not at all.  I have 45 year old 25kva transformers that were "rode hard and put away wet" and still perform to spec.